# How to don't quit batch file from another script with exit /b 0

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a program1.cmd file that finishes the commands with exit /b 0. This program cannot be edited.

I've created a test.bat and I must call program1.cmd, however, I need to process in sequence program2.cmd and then program3.exe. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call one batch file from another (whether `.BAT` or `.CMD`), you should use the `CALL` command to return to the calling batch file. See [SS64 on `CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) for more information. Using the information you gave in your question, `TEST.BAT` would contain the following commands:

```
CALL program1.cmd
CALL program2.cmd
program3
REM could also be CALL program3.exe, but doesn't need to be.
```

(*If the two `.CMD` files and the `.EXE` are not in the same directory as `TEST.BAT`, you would need to supply paths to them, not just the file names.*)

Comment: Jeff I have added the path of the files directories that I need with:

set CSEdir=C:\Program Files\...
set "path=%path%;%CSEdir%"

But the problem is that the .cmd that I call (I just used the name of the .cmd withou comand "call" and worked) finishes because of the exit /b 0. This lead to my .bat to close...

Comment: You MUST use `CALL` to prevent the initial batch file from closing.